# Error with CMAKE and manually compiled QT4

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, qt4

I am quite new to linux and I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64bits.

I acquired an open source code, and I need to compile it with cmake.
This code required QT4.

I downloaded a QT4.8.6 open source files and manually compiled them. (this is needed because QT no longer support pre-compiled QT4 for linux).

I added my "qmake" directory to my PATH variable. echo ${PATH} shows that.

When I compile the code with CMAKE, the following error appears :

> CMake Error at
>   /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148
>   (message):   Could NOT find Qt4 (missing: QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE
>   QT_RCC_EXECUTABLE   QT_UIC_EXECUTABLE) (found version "4.8.6") Call
>   Stack (most recent call first):
>   /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388
>   (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
>   /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1333
>   (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)   CMakeLists.txt:20 (FIND_PACKAGE)

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't need to download Qt 4 from qt.io, Ubuntu 16.04 has both [Qt 4.8.7](http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/xenial/libqt4-dev) and [Qt 5.5.1](http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/xenial/qtbase5-dev) compiled and available in the repositories
2. cmake finds Qt by looking for the `qmake` binary and other binaries. Unfortunately both Qt5 and Qt4 have those binaries, and Ubuntu solves that problem by installing Qt4 to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4`. You can make Qt4 the default (the one in your path) by installing the package `qt4-default`: `sudo apt install qt4-default` which will create symlinks from the qt4-specific folder (for example for qmake from `/usr/lib/.../qt4/bin/qmake` to `/usr/bin/qmake`. Now, `qmake --version` should print `Using Qt version 4.8.7 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`
3. This only applies when you use cmake on the command line. If you use QtCreator, your Kit configuration will apply.

I think the easiest way to solve your problem is just using the Qt 4 supplied by Ubuntu (by installing `qt4-default`), and removing your custom build Qt 4 and the PATH modifications.

Comment: Thank you very much. It actually worked this way. I didnt know ubuntu proposed Qt4 as a package. Thank you again.

Comment: No problem! Can you accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark to the left of it?